# Converter Jquery para Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde,

Gostaria de converter este código abaixo para Javascript:

```
                $('.circles > div').click(function () {
                    let index = $('.circles > div').index(this);
                    $('.circles > div').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                    $('.steps-carousel').css('transform', 'translateX(' + (index * -20) + '%)');
                });
```

Alguém poderia me auxiliar?

Comment: Já tentaste alguma coisa? Percebes esse código jQuery e o que ele faz? quais as linhas que não percebes?

Comment: Esse código foi um steps que criei com um carousel, porém criei ele em Jquery e onde irei implantar não utiliza o Jquery.

Comment: O que ele faz: Quando eu clico no círculo, ele remove a classe active e adiciona no círculo que cliquei e muda o item do carousel. Só que ele não funciona pois no sistema que vou implantar, ele não possui JQuery, dai tem que ser javascript puro

Comment: Sabes por exemplo o que `$('.circles > div').index(this);` faz?

Comment: Vamos lá:

dentro da classe "circles", possui divs sem nenhuma classe ou id, apenas div.

este "$('.circles > div').index(this);" armazena dentro da variável index (let index) a div que eu cliquei.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui fica uma sugestão, não testada mas com referência a que linha de código corresponde. Não tenho a certeza se no teu HTML `carousel` é só um elemento ou vários... mas corrige caso não seja.

```js
const carousel = document.querySelectorAll('.steps-carousel');
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.circles > div');

divs.forEach((div, index) => {
  // aqui o index é o mesmo que let index = $('.circles > div').index(this);
  div.addEventListener('click', () => { // $('.circles > div').click(function() {
    div.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active')); // $('.circles > div').removeClass('active');
    div.classList.add('active'); // $(this).addClass('active');
    carousel.forEach(el => el.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (index * -20) + '%)'); //$('.steps-carousel').css('transform', 'translateX(' + (index * -20) + '%)');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

document.querySelectorAll para utilizar queries como JavaScript.
Para atribuir classes/atributos a cada elemento você tem que iterar sobre cada um deles, utilizando forEach por exemplo.
Então é só utilizar os métodos nativos do JavaScript para fazer o que você precisa.

```
const circleDivs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.circles > div')];
const stepsCarousel = [...document.getElementsByClassName('steps-carousel')];

circleDivs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const index = circleDivs.indexOf(el);

  circleDivs.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
  el.classList.add('active');
  stepsCarousel.forEach(el => el.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (index * -20) + '%)');

}));
```